# can't figure out how to center tags on a tumblr theme? padding issue?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, css

I don't have experience in coding and I have a heavily modified theme for my blog. But for the longest time I just can't figure out how to center the tags. It's always off-center and to the right.

[image]

I remember modifying a value a while back and to this day I still can't find what I did wrong. I've been told it's a padding issue but i can't find where in the code to modify it from.

(they told me to look for ".tags" but i don't have that in my theme)

I can see it's off by 40px but despite looking in the code and individually changing each value to see if that affects it I've had no success. I truly am stumped.

[image]

I can even see the problem when I inspect it but I don't know what I should be looking for in order to modify it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What? It looks like it's in the centre

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise no. The music note is. The tags clearly are not. However this is nowhere near enough information for us to figure out what the problem is. Try paring down your code until it works to find the problem area, for starters (a "minimal working example" as it is usually known). As an aside, I believe HTML-centric questions usually belong over in the main https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think the source of your problem (as far as I can tell you also figured this out, but didn't bother to state so explicitly) is the `webkit-padding-start:40px;` instruction that's causing you trouble. It's the "base css" that your browser apply to a page before any other instruction is applied. It's what allows a bare HTMl page with no CSS to be legible and not just a long string of text.

You need to "zero out" that padding (the padding on `ul.tags`) by explicitly setting it to 0 (which is probably the instruction you deleted at some point).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307357 discusses that exact issue. A five minutes google search would have done the trick.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't know the difference between sites and I assumed my question could be answered here. I also didn't know the webkit padding could be manually edited or the difference between that and just regular tumblr theme editing. Because well, I'm not proficient in this at all. i can go in and change the value to zero on that editor. but this did answer my question, now i just need to figure out how to make it permanent because it doesn't affect the overall theme. i'll go onto stack overflow to ask that.

Comment: @jambalaya If an answer answered your question, click the arrow to the left of it to mark it as correct. It will give some reputation to both you and the answerer. As for making the change permanently, go to `https://www.tumblr.com/customize/[blogname]?redirect_to=/settings/blog/[blogname]` where `[blogname]` is your blog name without brackets. Then click "Edit theme" beneath your theme's name. Add `<style>ul.tags { padding: 0; }</style>` to the end of it